# Ruby assets not installing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So first off, this question spawns from me being fairly new to rails and just figuring this out as I go.

I am working on a project and have added a few gems to my gemfile since I started and I have encountered something that seems trivial to solve, but I can't figure it out. When I add a gem to my Gemfile and run `bundle` the assets that are associated with that gem are not being dropped into my assets directory.

For example, I just added [Leaflet Marker Cluster](https://github.com/scpike/leaflet-markercluster-rails) to my project, and this gem has 3 files that are needed in the assets folder, but after running `bundle`, they are no where to be found.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please check it in your browser whether assets are added or not, just check this URL: http://localhost:3000/assets/leaflet.markercluster-src.js.

Answer (score 0):

They won't be physically in your assets folder. You'll need to require them in your application.css/js manifest like this..

```
//=require leaflet.markercluster.js
```

Comment: So because leaflet.markercluster is just a plugin to leaflet, and if I already have "=require leaflet" in my manifest, then should I have to add your line as well? Or should it just work because markercluster is a plugin?

Comment: @SeanCallahan - Your application.js manifest file should look something like this https://gist.github.com/stuartchaney/d61d49e2994c62da2dc2 and your application.css file should look like this https://gist.github.com/stuartchaney/692c0af68fa5fdbcab77

Answer (score 0):

If you want the assets to be compiled inside the assets folder you have two options:

1- Add the asset you want on your manifest:

```
//= require some_file_from_your_plugin
```

2- Add the asset on your precompile assets array config:

config/environments/production.rb, go to config.assets.precompile and add the assets you want to compile there, like:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( my_asset1.css another_asset.js)
```

You need one each depending on how you implement each asset on your site:
- if you only load application.js you need to add the asset like in option 1
- if you use something like "= javascript_include_tag 'another_asset.js'" then you need option 2

I really recomend you take your time and read rails guide about assets http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html it's REALLY helpful, it covers almost anything you need to know about assets, cache, compression, minification.

Answer (score 0):

It has problems with rails-assets. Just look at this https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/394.

If you want to use leaflet.markercluster without wait a next release, here is solution for you.

`#= require leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js`